# .NET 6 (Core) MVC application - problem with ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core

.NET 6 (Core) MVC application. In view I have:

```
$("#mybtn").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/MyController/GetCustomer",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'id': 5 }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response, textStatus, xhr) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
});
```

and in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetCustomer(int? id) {
    if (id == null) {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return Json(new { msg = "Error in the request." });
    }
    var customer = _db.Customers.Find(id);
    return Json(customer);
}
```

It gets to the action method in controller, but the id is always null...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why `JSON.stringify`?  I've always just passed the object directly...

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact model binder does not know how to transform payload to a nullable primitive. Either pass the value from query as /MyController/GetCustomer?id=5 or define a proper class to class MyPayload {public int id {get; set;}} and in controller JsonResult GetCustomer(MyPayload  request)

Comment: You don't need to `JSON.stringify` Just post directly as `{ 'id': 5 }`

Answer (score 0):

> It gets to the action method in controller, but the id is always
> null... What am I doing wrong?

To begin with, you don't need to use `JSON.stringify({ 'id': 5 })` as `{ 'id': 5 }` already in json format. In addition, `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` is uncessary as well, Instead, you can do as following:

Correct Format:

```
$("#mybtn").click(function () {
              $.ajax({
                    url: "/MyController/GetCustomer",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { 'id': 5 },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response, textStatus, xhr) {
                        alert(response);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });


});
```

**Note:**   You are getting null in your controller because of using `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and   additional, Json parsing here `JSON.stringify()` these are only valid when you are sending parameter as object fashion. Just get rid of those two part, you are done.

Output:

[image]